# feed json data into html table

Tags: javascript, html, json, meteor

I need to build a table based on json response i'm getting when calling API,
calling the API and get the JSON works fine, just I didn't found any documentation about building a table and pass from x.js to x.html. I succeed to pass only 1 param/value from the json.

my json looks like this: (it's Jenkins API result)

```
    {
   "builds":
   [
       {
           "duration": 24503,
           "id": "2013-12-11_19-48-55",
           "number": 33,
           "result": "FAILURE",
           "timestamp": 1386791335164
       },
       {
           "duration": 24553,
           "id": "2013-12-11_19-00-27",
           "number": 32,
           "result": "FAILURE",
           "timestamp": 1386788427803
       },
       {
           "duration": 24237,
           "id": "2013-12-11_18-59-51",
           "number": 31,
           "result": "FAILURE",
           "timestamp": 1386788391179
       },
```

JS Code

```
    Meteor.call('jenkinsServiceBuild', function(err, respJson) {

    if(err) {
      window.alert("Error: " + err.reason);
      console.log("error occured on receiving data on server. ", err );
    } else {
      //window.alert("Success: ");
      console.log("respJson: ", respJson.builds[1].id);
      //window.alert(respJson.length + ' tweets received.');
      var buildsList = respJson.builds[1].id;
      Session.set("recentBuilds", respJson.builds[1].id);
    }
    $('#buildButton').removeAttr('disabled').val('build');
  })
},  
 });

    Template.dashboard.helpers({
recentBuilds : function() {
return Session.get("recentBuilds");
//recentBuilds: buildsList
```

}
});

HTML Code

```
<template name="dashboard">
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="button" value="build" class="btn btn-info" id="buildButton"/>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    ___{{recentBuilds}}___

    </template>
```

Thanks
Ronen

Comment: I ll recommend using a datable class from YUI or bootstrap it will make your work very easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this in your html instead of `___{{recentBuilds}}___`

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Duration</th><th>ID</th><th>Number</th><th>Result</th><th>Timestamp</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each recentBuilds}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{duration}}</td>
            <td>{{number}}</td>
            <td>{{result}}</td>
            <td>{{timestamp</td>
        </tr>
    {{else}}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">No data</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also in your callback return all the data instead of one value so it can be iterated through:

instead of

```
Session.set("recentBuilds", respJson.builds[1].id);
```

Return everything in `builds`.

```
Session.set("recentBuilds", respJson.builds);
```

So now because everything in `builds` is an array, when you use `{{#each}}` it would loop through these in your html and create a row for each one.

Comment: Thanks, I really needed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML

```
<table id="result">
  <tr>
    <th>Duration</th><th>ID</th><th>Number</th><th>Result</th><th>Timestamp</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Your JS

```
for (obj in respJson.builds) {
  var line = '<tr><td>' + obj.duration + '</td><td>' + obj.id + '</td><td>' + obj.number + '</td><td>' + obj.result + '</td><td>' + obj.timestamp + '</td><td>';
  $('#result').append(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you !.Using jquery ajax getjson

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
       
  var data=$.getJSON("test.js",function(data)
      {
       $.each(data.results,function( key, val ) 
          {
             
    $("div").append(val.jobtitle + " <br/>");
          });
 
      });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>


<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

[1. HTML FILE](https://orionhub.org/file/teluguwale-OrionContent/js/test.html)
     [2. JSON JS FILE](https://orionhub.org/file/teluguwale-OrionContent/js/test.js)